# How to replace subset of pandas dataframe with on other series

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, missing-data

I think this is a trivial question, but i just cant make it work.

```
d = {   'one': pd.Series([1,2,3,4], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']),
            'two': pd.Series([np.nan,6,np.nan,8], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']),
            'three': pd.Series([10,20,30,np.nan], index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}         
   ​    
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df

    one     three   two
a   1       10.0    NaN
b   2       20.0    6.0
c   3       30.0    NaN
d   4       NaN     8.0
```

My serires:

```
​fill = pd.Series([30,60])
```

I'd like to replace a specific column, let it be 'two'. With my Series called fill, where the column 'two' meets a condition: is Nan. Canyou help me with that?
 My desired result:

```
df

    one     three   two
a   1       10.0    30
b   2       20.0    6.0
c   3       30.0    60
d   4       NaN     8.0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need `loc` with [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) for replace `numpy array` created from `fill` by [`Series.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
df.loc[df.two.isnull(), 'two'] = fill.values
print (df)
   one  three   two
a    1   10.0  30.0
b    2   20.0   6.0
c    3   30.0  60.0
d    4    NaN   8.0
```